# How do I use ResourceBundle::getLocales()?

Tags: php, locale, resourcebundle, icu

Given I have a directory `/locales` with the files `root.res` and `es.res`, which have been generated (using `genrb`) from the text files as follows:

File: `root.txt`

```
root:table {
    test:string { "My test text" }
}
```

File: `es.txt`

```
es:table {
    test:string { "Mi texto de prueba" }
}
```

When I run the following code:

```php
<?php
$bundleName = 'locale';
$resourceBundle = new ResourceBundle('es', $bundleName);
echo join("\n", $resourceBundle->getLocales($bundleName));
```

I should see:

```
es
root
```

However, the code produces:

```
Warning: join(): Invalid arguments passed...
```

This happens because `$resourceBundle ->getLocales($bundleName)` returns `bool(false)`, but running the following code for locale *es*:

```php
<?php
$bundleName = 'locale';
$resourceBundle = new ResourceBundle('es', $bundleName);
echo ($resourceBundle->get('test') . "\n");
```

correctly outputs:

```
Mi texto de prueba
```

And running for locale *root*:

```php
<?php
$bundleName = 'locale';
$resourceBundle = new ResourceBundle('root', $bundleName);
echo ($resourceBundle->get('test') . "\n");
```

correctly outputs:

```
My test text
```

What do I need to do to make `getLocales()` work?

Answer (score 0):

So, the PHP Manual, as usual, is not clear about this. However, the [ICU Web site](http://userguide.icu-project.org/design#TOC-Resource-Bundle-Inheritance-Model) is:

> A resource bundle is a set of  pairs that provide a mapping from key to value. A given program can have different sets of resource bundles; one set for error messages, one for menus, and so on. However, the program may be organized to combine all of its resource bundles into a single related set.
>
> The set is organized into a tree with "root" at the top, the language at the first level, the country at the second level, and additional variants below these levels. The set must contain a root that has all keys that can be used by the program accessing the resource bundles.

I will return with an update when tested.